# Trying to push large number of commits in batches

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I'm working on a extremely large project that needs to migrate from Team Foundation Services to Git. I performed the local conversion successfully, garnering 2800+ commits that need to be pushed to github. A few of these commits are pretty large and a simple git push gets about 3% of the way in before returning the following error:

```
fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size
```

There seems to be a roughly 2.9gb limit on the size of an upcoming pack. That seemed reasonable, so I've been searching on Stackoverflow to see how I can push these commits up. I swapped to using SSH, but the error still persists but then I came across this line of GIT Bash code in a comment that seems to aim towards what I want (sending up the commits in batches):

```
max=$(git log --oneline|wc -l); for i in $(seq $max -500 1); do echo $i; g=$(git log --reverse --oneline --skip $i -n1|perl -alne'print $F[0]'); git push gh $g:refs/heads/master; done
```

The challenge is that the comment didn't really mention  how this command works or how to modify it to get it working for my sitaution. I run the code as-is and get the following error:

```
'gh' does not appear to be a git repository
```

Thinking I know what I'm doing I attempting the follow alternate line of bash code:

```
max=$(git log --oneline|wc -l); for i in $(seq $max -500 1); do echo $i; g=$(git log --reverse --oneline --skip $i -n1|perl -alne'print $F[0]'); git push origin $g:refs/heads/master; done
```

This returns the following error:

```
[remote rejected] master (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master)
```

Clearly I'm doing something wrong but I don't know enough about Git Bash to know what. Can anyone help me figure out what I should have typed in there?

git branch results:

- master

Comment: does your project contain large binary objects?

Comment: A couple - plus a massive number of source files

Comment: I don't thing the souce files are the problem. I suspect it's the LBOs. Is there any chance to restart the migration and to do a separate commit for each LBO?

Comment: The LBOs are in separate commits, but Git is packing all the commits into one giant pack during upload. I'm hoping to stagger the uploads in blocks of 500 commits to keep under the pack limit.

Comment: possible workaround: create a branch at the commit before the  LBO commit and push this branch. reset the branch to the LBO commit and push again repeat this for each LBO commit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
max=$(git log --oneline|wc -l); for i in $(seq $max -500 1); do echo $i; git push origin master~$i:refs/heads/master; done; git push origin master
```

Explanation:

```
max=$(git log --oneline|wc -l)
```

This lists all commits in the current branch and count the number of commits.

```
for i in $(seq $max -500 1); do … done
```

Run a loop assigning `i` numbers from `$max` to 1 decrementing by 500 at the every loop.

```
git push origin master~$i:refs/heads/master
```

Push old commits up to `master~$i`. This is executed in the loop above decreasing `i` so you push commits like `HEAD~10000`, `HEAD~9500`, `HEAD~9000`, etc thus pushing commits in batches by 500 commits in a batch.

```
git push origin master
```

After all commits have been pushed update remote-tracking branch so it remembers you've pushed all commits in `master`.

Comment: This was a huge help.

Comment: Using `git push origin main~$i:refs/heads/main` i got this error: `error: src refspec main~500 does not match any`. I don't know why..

Comment: @mateonunez Most probably you don't have branch `main`, you have branch `master`. If you have a different question you should ask it as a question, not as a comment. Comments are for improvement of questions and answers.

Comment: I got this working but had to use `${i}` to get the interpolation to work correctly.

So the full thing was:
`max=$(git log --oneline|wc -l); for i in $(seq $max -500 1); do echo $i; git push origin master~${i}:refs/heads/master; done; git push origin master`

Answer (score 0):

Addition to @phd' answer:
If there are merge commits, should use

```
git log --oneline --first-parent|wc -l
```

to count commits.