# Github: Send git objects incrementally (or in separate batches)

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-push

I have a repo that has a lot of small files (the `.git` directory is 4.2GB, but almost all the files are 4KB). When I try pushing it to Github, I get:

```
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

```
❯ git send-pack --all git@github.com:x/y.git
Connection to github.com closed by remote host.
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Enumerating objects: 2033590, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2033590/2033590), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1513323/1513323), done.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Can I send the git objects incrementally to Github to work around this?

PS: The same thing happens with Gitlab

```
❯ git push gl master         
Connection to gitlab.com closed by remote host.
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Enumerating objects: 2033590, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2033590/2033590), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1513323/1513323), done.
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: You could create branches at separate parts of the branch (or branches) you want to send and then push them "in order" so that in the end you push the full branch, then you could delete the intermediate remote branches. I wonder if this is the root cause, anyway.

Comment: @eftshift0 The repo has been just created, so this is the first commit. So the best solution is to delete this commit, and create commits with a batch of files added at a time?

Comment: Note that you may have hit one of those "interesting" (cough) cases here, where your local Git takes so long enumerating, counting, and compressing objects that the other Git gets impatient and hangs up the Internet-phone. :-)

Comment: @torek It takes around 7 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

> The repo has been just created, so this is the first commit. So the best solution is to delete this commit, and create commits with a batch of files added at a time?

Yes: creating multiple smaller commits instead of one giant commit will ensure you will be able to push them.

As an example of such a push, see "[Trying to push large number of commits in batches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273901/6309)"

```
max=$(git log --oneline|wc -l); \
for i in $(seq $max -500 1); do \
  echo $i; \
  git push origin master~$i:refs/heads/master; \
done; \
git push origin master
```