# How to find the commit in a mirrored git repo which is exactly at the middle of commits count?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs, github-for-windows, github-enterprise

**Context:**

Migrating huge repos (size>2GB) from GHES to GHEC.

**Problem:**

I have a repo which is of size 3.3 GB which needs to be mirror cloned and pushed to GHEC.

When pushing the repo to GHEC, I'm getting the below error.

```
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size (2.00 GiB)
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (282092/282092), 3.22 GiB | 55.08 MiB/s, done.
Total 282092 (delta 204318), reused 282092 (delta 204318), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I see few articles where they suggested to push some commit where the repo size is less than 2GB.
https://discourse.llvm.org/t/fyi-llvm-project-repo-has-exceeded-github-upload-size-limit/63293

But how do I find that commit where the repo size is < 2GB. My repo has around 37000 commits in it.

Comment: Do it in small batches: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51273901/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+batches

Comment: @phd This is what I'm getting with above answers `fatal: --mirror can't be combined with refspecs`

Comment: There is no `--mirror` in my advice, don't know why you added it.

Comment: @Underoos: drop `--mirror` (sorry for the obviousness ...) Start by pushing chunks of data with a limited size, from an identified branch to an identified branch (e.g: local `refs/heads/main` to remote `refs/heads/main`). *After* you have pushed enough data that way, *do* run `git push --mirror` to sync other branches -- if you pushed enough data in the first step, the amount of data to send should be small enough to go through.